# How to get unmatched elements in an nsmutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `NsMutableArray`. I filtered matched data with `NSPredicate` but i want that array element which is not matched.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Add details of what you have tried so far. What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT` with the `predicate` for that

```
NSArray *arrValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hello",@"Hello One",@"Good Morning", nil];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF CONTAINS %@)",@"Hello"];  
NSArray *arrFiltered  = [arrValues filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@",arrFiltered);
```

Output

```
(
   "Good Morning"
)
```

Comment: Thanks its working. Can you tell me one thing can with use more than one parameter in NSPredicate like [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF CONTAINS %@%@)",@"Hello","Good Morning"];